# Error al quedar vacío el TextBox con evento KeyUp o TextChange

Tags: c#

Tengo un *TextBox* en el que había creado el evento `TextChange`, pero lo cambié porque al quedar vacío se genera un error. Cambié el evento a `KeyUp`, y no pude solucionarlo.

---

Este es el codigo que tengo, es simple pero no puedo solucionarlo:

```
private void txtprec_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        double prec, isv;
        prec = double.Parse(txtprec.Text);
        isv = prec * 0.15 + prec;
        result_isv.Text = isv.ToString();
    }
```

Funciona, pero al momento de quedar en cero muestra el error:

> System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Comment: ¿Puedes enseñar el código y el mensaje del error?

Comment: Saludos puedes especificar tus datos de entrada y la salida esperada para poder apoyarte con la solución

Comment: Hola, edita la pregunta e indica en texto el código que has intentado realizar. 
Así será mas fácil ayudarte, y evitarás que te cierren la pregunta por baja calidad.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es común, si chequeas la documentación del método [`Double.Parse`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.double.parse?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Double.Parse);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) verás que puede disparar un [`FormatException`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.formatexception?view=netframework-4.8) debido, según microsoft, a:

> `s` no representa un número con un formato válido.

**¿Cómo lo solucionamos?**

Es sencillo, debemos estar seguros que el parámetro que le enviaremos a [`Double.Parse`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.double.parse?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Double.Parse);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) sea un número válido, en caso de no estarlo, podemos usar otro método, útil en estos casos, [`Double.TryParse`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Double.TryParse);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8).

El método [`TryParse`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Double.TryParse);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) se encargará de verificar que el string recibido es un double válido, y en caso de serlo, lo asignará en una variable debido al uso de la palabra clave [`out`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(out_CSharpKeyword)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%3Dv4.7.2)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue).

Sabiendo esto, podemos ir a la práctica.

```
private void txtprec_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //Definimos las variables..
    double isv, prec;
    //¿Es el valor de txtprec.Text un número válido?
    //En caso de serlo, se asignará a la variable out, sino, irá directo al else.
    if (double.TryParse(txtprec.Text, out prec))
    {
        //Realizamos el cálculo y lo asignamos a la propiedad Text del resultado..
        isv = prec * 0.15 + prec;
        result_isv.Text = isv.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        //En caso de que no haya sido un double válido, vaciamos el Text del resultado.
        result_isv.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```